# Rails setting macros in module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to setup belongs_to, validates, and default scopes in a module.

```
module MultiTenancy
  class TenantNotSetError < StandardError ; end

  def self.included(model)
    class << model
      belongs_to :tenant
      validates :tenant_id, presence: true
      default_scope -> {
        raise TenantNotSetError.new unless Tenant.current_tenant
        where(tenant_id: Tenant.current_tenant.id)
      }

      def multi_tenanted?
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I keep getting a

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `belongs_to' for #<Class:User>
```

error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your `User` class inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def self.included(base)
  base.class_eval do
    # your code goes here
  end
end
```

The reason it doesn't work is you try to call `belongs_to` on metaclass of `User`, not on `User`.